# O que significa "aconteça o que acontecer"?

Tags: ortografia, expressões

O que significa "**aconteça o que acontecer**"?

Eu sei que aconteça  é subjuntivo presente e acontecer é subjuntivo futuro! 
Que tipo se estrutura é isso? Por que eles vão numa sentença juntos?

Outra exemple é **"Seja quem for, diga que não estou**"!

Que tipo de estrutura é isso e o que quer dizer?

Comment: A melhor definição para *aconteça o que acontecer* é *independente do que acontecer...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

São [**orações justapostas**](http://portuguescienciaviva.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/oracoes-justapostas.html)

> - As orações justapostas são aquelas orações colocadas uma ao lado da outra sem qualquer conectivo que as enlace, este tipo de oração coordenada chama-se assindética.

Segundo Evanildo Bechara, são [**orações justapostas concessivas**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kA5LywXfV-kC&pg=PT510&lpg=PT510&dq=%22custe+o+que+custar%22+gram%C3%A1tica&source=bl&ots=E6l5g9HcuD&sig=OrxiY0Lr0k_16YMYaRh5FsQZ8Fo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp29Xc4NDYAhWLkpAKHR6gDWUQ6)

> A justaposição pode, ao nível do texto, apresentar as seguintes interpretações: concessivas, condicionais, temporais e finais.
>
> - concessivas - tendo o verbo no subjuntivo anteposto ao sujeito ou caracterizadas por expressões do tipo "custe o que custar", "dê onde der", "aconteça o que acontecer", "venha de onde vier", etc.  Não é o subjuntivo que de per si denota a concessão, mas sim o contexto e a entoação decrescente.

E essas expressões significam "não importa..." ou "independente do que..."

- "aconteça o que acontecer", não importa o que aconteça.
- "custe o que custar", não importa o quanto custe.
- "seja quem for", não importa quem seja.